# How to limit no of threads read from config file C# framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have an application similar to sample C# code this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx).
In this example, there is no limit to the no of threads generated.

Could someone provide me sample code to limit the no of thread (read from config file) generated.
I am using framework 3.5. i don't have a provision to upgrade to 4.0.

Thanks in advance --Joxin

Comment: what about counting threads? add a var that counts the number of threads reading, and each thread well check if he could read.

Comment: No, that code does **not** create an unlimited number of threads.  It can only create 10 at most.  Putting it in a .config file is not a good idea, the user will not know enough to guess at a decent value.  Which is Environment.ProcessorCount, ideally, for code like that.  It is not a very good example.

Comment: @ Hans.. i agree that it create 10 and all 10 threads are cretaed at once but i want to limit no of threads ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ThreadPool` class does have the option to [`SetMaxThreads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx), which will allow you to set the maximum number of threads.

That being said, this is rarely a good idea - at least not as a permanent setting/change.  It can be beneficial to do this, and then restore the previous max threads, for a specific algorithm, however.

Note that .NET 4's TPL does make this far simpler, and is usable in .NET 3.5 if you install the [Rx framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26649), as the 3.5 version includes a back port of the TPL for .NET 3.5.  This provides the functionality to limit the work directly for a routine (via [ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx)).

Comment: @vidstige Yes, they can - though there are many benefits to using the `ThreadPool` in most cases.  Manually creating threads is rarely a good idea (though it can be the best option, in certain cases).

Comment: Hi Reed, thx 4 quick reply. i have installed Rx-Framework . and added reference to System.Reactive .but that doesn't help ..did i miss something?

Comment: @joXin You'd have to add a reference to `System.Threading.dll` too (which also ships with it - at least it used to be a separate assembly...)

Comment: @ Reed .. using System.Threading; this is already there..and multi threading is alreadt in place.. i need to limit the no..

Comment: @joXin Rx's System.Threading.dll adds the new `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx)

Comment: @joXin Can you add `using System.Threading.Tasks;` and make a `Task`?

Comment: @ reed, googled and seems like the latest version doesn't contain that dll shipped....

Comment: @joXin You need to grab an older release. See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/527002a3-18af-4eda-8e35-760ca0006b98#11b85c5b-f966-4b2a-9a94-b5d1c41394b7

Comment: @ Reed, thx..got the dll from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24940